# C# 2D Game Library?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, slick

I'm looking for a C# 2D game library based on something like OpenTK which wraps OpenGL for C#

Basically something like Slick2D (2D game library for Java) which is based on LWJGL which is an OpenGL wrapper for Java.

Is there something like this for C#?

Comment: FlatRedBall is pretty good, albeit it's XNA-like, not OpenGL-like

Answer (score 1):

There's [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net), I believe it is an XNA implementation that works on Mono by using OpenGL.

Comment: XNA (and thus Monogame) are not 2D libraries or engines. They're frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little library called [AssortedWidgets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/assortedwidgets/) which is a GUI application using OpenTK. You can read a bit about it [here](http://www.opentk.com/node/2103).

It allows GUI interfaces like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you're searching for, but still.

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/602858-first-duality-demonstration/